# Core dump file not generated on segmentation fault

Tags: c, linux, gdb, coredump

I am trying to debug a segmentation fault caused by my C program using `gdb`. A core dump file is not automatically generated when I run my program,and i have to run the command

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

for a core file to be generated on the next run.

Why is a core dump file not generated automatically and why do I have to run the `ulimit` command everytime to generate a core file on the next run of my program ?.

The operating system i use is Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to place the command

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

in your environment settings.

If you are using bash as your shell, you need to place the above command in ~/.bashrc

Answer (score 16):

You might also want to try to edit `/etc/security/limits.conf` file instead of adding `ulimit -c unlimited` to `~/.bashrc`.

The `limits.conf` is the "correct" place where to specify core dump details in most Linux distros.

Answer (score 9):

That's because by default your distribution limits core file size to 0 blocks. The `ulimit` command you mentioned increases that limit to infinity.

I don't know about Ubuntu, but most distros have a file /etc/limits with system defaults for resource limits.

Answer (score -1):

The segmentation fault is due to irrelevant values for path variables. On my system the user is `sidd@sidd-Lenovo-G460` and the contents added are as below.

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/sidd/ns-allinone-2.35/bin:/home/sidd/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/unix:/home/sidd/ns-allinone-2.35/tk8.5.10/unix

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/sidd/ns-allinone-2.35/otcl-1.14:/home/sidd/ns-allinone-2.35/lib

TCL_LIBRARY=/home/sidd/ns-allinone-2.35/tcl8.5.10/library
```

Please refer [this blog post](http://vibhanshu86.wordpress.com/2014/06/17/installing-ns2-on-ubuntu-14-04/) (VERY IMPORTANT).